Can't execute session mobaxterm
So I recently had to do a clean windows install so I exported my session and reimported them. But now I can't execute them anymore, if I double click on them or right click and execute it just show a loading ring on the cursor for half a second and then nothing. Can someone help me?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Have you verified that the IPs are still correct?  Have you tried to add a new one to see if that works?  What kind of sessions?  Are they all the same type?  Throw a monkey a banana for Pete's sake!

Yeah the IP are still correct and by trying to recreate the same session by scratch I have the same problem. It's a SSH session and I don't have any other just this. I think there might be a problem with the jump host being that even trying to ping it give negative results
